# Select columns from one table into another and create variables with default value at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create a new table based on another table.  Also I want to create new variables at the same time, specify their data type and assign a default value.

My code is the following for now:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#test2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test2
SELECT TOP 100
    ID_number
    ,name = CHAR(10)
INTO #test2
FROM #test1
```

The following does not work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#test2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test2
SELECT TOP 100
    ID_number
    ,name = CHAR(10) DEFAULT 'asdf'
INTO #test2
FROM #test1
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can we assume that #test2 is the table you are trying to create in this situation? Also, is the default value an override (IE, replace the name with this default value) or just when the name is blank/NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT TOP 100
    ID_number
    , CONVERT(CHAR(10), ISNULL(name, 'asdf'))
INTO #test2
FROM #test1
```

It won't add a default constraint to the new table, but any nulls will be replaced. It should also pick up the `CHAR(10)` type. But to be sure, I'd recommend explicitly creating the table in order to control its structure.

Also note: If you want empty strings to be treated like nulls, use:

`ISNULL(NULLIF(name, ''), 'DefaultValue')`

Answer (score 0):

Granted, this is making some assumptions about your tables, but if you are using `#test1` to create `#test2`, this might be the solution to your problem. This also assumes that you want to use a Default Value when you have a `NULL` or blank string.

If you provide more information, I can modify the answer.

```
-- Creates some basic schema/data
CREATE TABLE #test1 (
    ID_number INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name CHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #test1
SELECT TOP 100 LEFT(o.name,10)
FROM sys.objects o

UPDATE #test1
SET name = NULL
WHERE ID_number % 5 = 0

UPDATE #test1
SET name = ''
WHERE ID_number % 7 = 0

-- Your answer here
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#test2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test2

SELECT TOP 100
    ID_number,
    CASE 
        WHEN name IS NULL THEN 'DEFAULT'
        WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(name)) = '' THEN 'DEFAULT'
        ELSE name
    END AS name
INTO #test2
FROM #test1

-- Verification and cleanup
SELECT * FROM #test2
SELECT * FROM #test1

DROP TABLE #test1
```